# Custom OnItemClickListener from CursorAdapter in ListView AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

I'm working in an Android project, and I wanted to show an AlertDialog with a ListView. So, I started creating a class extending DialogFragment, and I also want to create a code that serves for several calls

(Each activity that needs the ListView in an AlertDialog, can call this class, but this ListView can use any CursorAdapter).

I know the usually way to use `setOnItemClickListener`, but, as I want to work with any CursorAdapter, how can I retrieve the clicked Item, with all the fields of this particular Cursor?

Thanks!

My class looks like this:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

    String title;
    String message;
    CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    //  
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstances){
        this.setRetainInstance(true);
        //
        Dialog dialog;

                ListView listViewCursorAdapter = new ListView(getActivity());
                listViewCursorAdapter.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
                //
                listViewCursorAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    }
                });
                //
                dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle(title)
                        .setMessage(message)
                        .setView(listViewCursorAdapter)
                        .create();

}
```

Comment: Naming ListView instance ListViewCursorADAPTER is bad and misleasing. Maybe after naming it better, you will have clear situation.

Comment: @Bozic I named the instance of ListView as listViewCursorAdapter, because I had others instances for ListView using arrays and other. I didn't post the entire code because it would be big to read and not focused in the question

Answer (score 0):

Get the cursor from CursorAdapter

```
Cursor cursor = listViewCursorAdapter.getCursor();
```

then move it to desired position

```
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
```